# How do I get the generated domain name for local URL's for a Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

I have a Windows 8 app that downloads the online assets, unzips them into the `LocalState` folder, and accesses that content when the user is offline. I use a custom `IUriStreamResolver` to provide the content. The local URL might look like this:

```
ms-local-stream://package-name_application-key/.../.../
```

The part I'm after is the `application-key`. While the `package-name` is in the `Package.appmanifest`, the `application-key` is not. I've also verified the `package-key` is not part of the `LocalState` path. I'm wanting to use [`WebView.BuildLocalStreamUri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.buildlocalstreamuri.aspx) and it requires the `contentIdentifier`, this is documented as the concatenation of the `package-name` and `application-key`.

I've done quite a bit of digging through the API's via the Object Browser, and of course I've pretty much exhausted Google and DuckDuckGo (love that search engine BTW), and they've not provided any fruit.

Does anybody know how I can get at that key the app generates and uses for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't actually matter what the value is. It has no bearing on the URL that is formed. I wanted to answer this for the next person trying to use this method. It just **cannot** be `null` or an empty `string`.